# limit-of-search to apply search-forward to just current paragraph

Tags: search, thing-at-point

The search-forward function takes four arguments:

```
(search-forward "target-string"
                limit-of-search
                what-to-do-if-search-fails
                repeat-count)
```

The second argument (limit-of-search) bounds the search. it is specified as a position in the buffer. In this case, the search can go to the end of the buffer, so no bound is set and the second argument is nil.

How to set it to just search until the end of the current paragraph?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it seems not be officially documented, we find from [this thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2020-11/msg00049.html) that `thing-at-point` can be used with `paragraph`.

Therefore, you can simply use `(cdr (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'paragraph))`.

For example:

```lisp
(while (search-forward ". "
                       (cdr (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'paragraph))
                       t)
  (delete-backward-char 1)
  (insert "\n\n"))
```

Comment: I did not get that. Could you write the exact syntax? My function is:  (while (search-forward ". " nil t) (delete-backward-char 1) (insert "\n\n")). Where shall I add that code? Thanks!

Comment: Got it, thanks, it is not working for some reason. It is doing nothing to my text.

Comment: This is what I am using:  (while (search-forward ". " (end-of-thing 'paragraph) t) (delete-backward-char 1) (insert "\n\n"))

Comment: Sorry, my answer is wrong, I did not check it correctly.

Comment: I have corrected it... (while checking the 'wrong answer', it seemed that it stopped searching at the end of the paragraph, but of course it just moved the point there. I was a little sloppy).

Comment: Thank you!!! It does work now!